# Trying to build a grid of labels that can be updated from a loop

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, while-loop, grid

I'm trying to write a ping program that reads IPs from a csv and then pings them and then displays in a GUI whether or not they are online. I've gotten stuck at the point that I can spawn the GUI and create the labels but can not get the labels to update. Ideally I would like the bg colour to be green if online and red if offline.

If I'm using the wrong tool for the job, I'm open to suggestions as I am really new to this stuff. Thanks for taking the time to offer any help. I feel like its so close to what I want but I've been banging my head against this for far longer than I care to admit.

---

```
import os
import subprocess as sp 
import time 
import csv 
import tkinter 

root = tkinter.Tk()
root.title("Branch Pinger")

with open("hosts4.csv",'r') as csv_file: 
    addresses = csv.reader(csv_file)
    for row in addresses:
        label = tkinter.Label(root, text = row[1], relief = tkinter.RIDGE, bg="white", width=10, height=3)
        label.pack()

while True:
    with open("hosts4.csv",'r') as csv_file: 
        addresses = csv.reader(csv_file)
        for row in addresses:
            log = open("{}.csv".format(row[1]) ,"a") 
            print()
            print(time.strftime('%H:%M:%S System Pinging now:',))
            status,result = sp.getstatusoutput('ping -c 2 {}'.format(row[0])) 
            if status == 0: 
                print(time.strftime(row[1] + " is UP!")) 
                log.write(time.strftime("%D %H:%M:%S System " + row[1] + " is UP!\n")) 
                log.close() 
                root.update_idletasks()
                root.update()
            else:
                print(time.strftime(row[1] + " is --DOWN!--")) 
                log.write(time.strftime("%D %H:%M:%S System " + row[1] + " is Down!\n"))  
                log.close()
                root.update_idletasks()
                root.update()
```

---

Comment: you have to keep all `label` on list and then you ahve access to all of them and you can change color.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a customized `Label` which can update itself based on the `ping` result periodically using `.after()`, like below:

```
import csv
import sys
import subprocess as sp
import time
import tkinter as tk

class HostStatus(tk.Label):
    if sys.platform == 'win32':
        __ping_cmd = 'ping -n 1 -w 1000 {} > nul'
    else:
        __ping_cmd = 'ping -c 1 -W 1 {} > /dev/null'

    def __init__(self, host, parent=None, sleep_ms=1000):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.config(text=host, fg='white', bg='grey', relief=tk.RIDGE, width=10, height=3)
        self.host = host
        self.sleep_ms = sleep_ms # period in miniseconds
        self.ping_cmd = self.__ping_cmd.format(host) # construct the ping command
        self.after(100, self.ping_check)

    def ping_check(self):
        status, _ = sp.getstatusoutput(self.ping_cmd)
        self.config(bg=('red' if status else 'green'))
        self.update_idletasks()
        self.log_status(status)
        self.after(self.sleep_ms, self.ping_check) # schedule next update

    def log_status(self, status):
        with open('{}.log'.format(self.host), 'a') as log:
            print('[{}] System {} is {}!'.format(time.strftime('%D %T'), self.host, 'UP' if status == 0 else 'DOWN'), file=log)

win = tk.Tk()
win.title('Branch Pinger')

with open('hosts4.csv') as csv_file:
    for row in csv.reader(csv_file):
        HostStatus(row[1], win).pack(side=tk.LEFT)

win.mainloop()
```